# Kotlin Kmongo insert and return inserted item

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin

I just tried to make a clean dummy project in Kotlin to practice but as Java does Kotlin does the same way the insert method. I tought it'll be some other way to insert and get back item not the old way to make 2 requests.

```
fun insert(book: Book) : Book? {
   getByEan(book.EAN)?.let {
     return null
   }
   mongo.collection.insertOne(book)
   return getByEan(book.EAN)
}
```

So in this case I made a pre-check to not make to items with same EAN and then if succeeded then return the inserted item.

Can it be more simple? Maybe pre-check made with an index or somehow get back the inserted item without a new request?

Comment: Technically speaking the only thing that actually returns the document would be a method like `.findOneAndUpdate()` with an "upsert" option set. Bu the question remains that if you are "inserting" the document then surely you have the content already. So since `.insert()` will return the new `_id` value, that should really be the only information you didn't have that is in the database. Isn't it? And if you have other data that is "unique", then either use that for the `_id` or create a "unique index" to stop it being created with duplicate information in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! You got the point! I see now how should I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fun insert(book: Book) : Book? {
    getByEan(book.EAN)?.let {
        return null
    }
    return book.apply { mongo.collection.insertOne(book) }
}

data class Book(val name: String, val EAN: Int, val author: String, val _id: String? = null)
```

By adding an _id field to the data model after the insertion it'll set the value with the generated id. In this case this code snippet will return the inserted object as I wanted without a plus request to the database.